# Linking boost library to c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I wanna use MySQL Connector/C++ in Visual Studio. So i read I need Boost library. I got that library and build it as explained in tutorial. I set include directories in Visual Studio to point to Boost include folder, and also set Additional Library Directories to point to boost_1_54_0\stage\lib , but which lib file should I include in Additional Dependencies? I can see that library for smart pointers is used but I cant find which lib file is that?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with just the includes?  As I recall, this are just template .hpp classes that need no library.

Comment: boost is set of libraries, many of them are header only libraries

Comment: Then maybe its mysql error. Here is an error: class 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection'

Answer (score 4):

If you are only going to build with Visual Studio, boost supports auto-linking. As long as the compiler can find the libraries that are not header only, boost should take care of this for you. More information can be found here: [Boost Auto Linking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking)